# How to interface Paypal with Flash for games

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, paypal

I have looked for something like this on Google and on this very site, but only found answers detailing procedures for sites. How is it possible to make so financial transactions can be carried over inside the game using Paypal, or maybe a different site? Is there any API/Library? If possible provide a solution in AS3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a PayPal API for this you would need to look through paypal documents to know to get further information, Apart from implementing this, a while back i had some scripts that would make a basic ECART for PayPal in actionScript, I would i have to check up my back up files to see if i still have them, i had found them through google..

Answer (score 0):

Paypal has a couple short examples of integrating their new Digital Goods payment method into Flash, but it either involves embedding javascript in the html surrounding your swf and talking to it using ExternalInterface, or opening another page in a popup.

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_IntegratingDigitalGoodsInFlash